# Fncychap with Conny option cannot produce table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, fncychap

I am writing a thesis using the `fncychap` package with the option `Conny`.

When trying to add a table of contents, I get the following error

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> \label@name {#1}\label@hook \protected...
>
> l.169 \tableofcontents\label #1->@bsphack \begingroup \def

I noticed that when removing the package, the ToC is normally generated.

A sample `.tex` document can be seen here

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}%Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

I also tried to load the `tocloft` by using `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` but I was still receiving the same error.

Any idea on how to generate the ToC while using the Conny option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
\UCTfalse
\tableofcontents
```

Better solution: don't use `fncychap`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But why not use `fncychap`? Is there any alternative?

Comment: @Thanos My personal opinion is that the chapter styles provided by the package are among the worst I've ever seen. Connie, in particular, is good for obituaries, rather than books.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. Is there however an alternative way of generating chapter styles? You can do it in `tikz`, but it might not be straightforward.